# PHP enable sqlite phpinfo states --without-sqlite

Tags: php, php.ini, sqlite

I've seen similar questions but none that address my situation adequately.  I'm running Apache and PHP 5.3.6 on a amazon cloud server.

phpinfo keeps stating that sqlite is disabled. At least that what it seems from the configure line:

```
'./configure' ... '--without-sqlite'
```

In other parts of phpinfo() output:

```
PDO
PDO drivers     mysql, sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.6.20 

sqlite3
SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.6.20

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value
```

and at least one the following PHP commands fail:

```
if (!extension_loaded('SQLite') OR !function_exists('sqlite_open'))
```

Yum install states that both sqlite and pdo-lite are already installed.

I've tried to enable sqlite by editing my local php.ini by adding:

```
; Enable sqlite3 extension module
extension=sqlite3.so
```

I've checked the main php.ini (/etc/php.ini) and there is nothing specific about disabling it.  In fact, there is a sub-conig file loaded in php.d that also specifies this extension as well as another for the pdo-sqlite

I'm running of things to look for or try.  Any suggestions.

How do I find where the PHP configure is stated?

Thanks

Comment: the extension_loaded function is rather contextual. Just check if any of the sqlite_ functions are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't specify the extension name correctly, so of course it fails. The correct extension name, as we see, is `sqlite3`.

```
if (!extension_loaded('SQLite')...
```

Anyway.

The RPM build of PHP actually rebuilds PHP four separate times. It is built once without any extensions enabled, for loading into Apache as `mod_php`, then built again with all extensions as shared memory objects. And a build for the PHP command line, and a fourth build whose purpose I forget right now.

So what happens is, the builds with no extensions built in are bundled with the extensions built from the other build. Thus PHP may say that it was configured without any extensions, yet still be able to use them.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for contributing an answer.  But, my eyes still aren't seeing the where this is happening.  Could you be a bit more specific as to where?  I can't recall how I moved on from this issue.

Comment: @Jahmic `SQLite` isn't the same as `sqlite3`. :)

Comment: I see now...  Anyways, long moved on from this issue. forget how, but thus far, this seems like the most likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `/etc/php.ini` appeared in the **Loaded Configuration File** line.

`--without-sqlite` don't talk about whether sqlite library is installed or not. Search `sqlite` in `phpinfo()` page to see if you have **SQLite Library** enabled.

Comment: It is, indeed, the loaded configuration file.  But I think there is some configure file somewhere passed at init time.  Where would that be?

Comment: In other parts of phpinfo() output: PDO: PDO drivers  mysql, sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x enabled
SQLite Library  3.6.20 

sqlite3
SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.6.20

Directive Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir no value no value

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're doing `phpinfo();` make sure you're looking at right php.ini (I think all of us been there where you're looking at one php.ini when another php.ini is being used) so look at "`Loaded Configuration File`", and another thing look at "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" on my RHEL system it shows that I have `/etc/php.d/` where more of php.ini files resides (including sqlite3.ini).